# How to display C# code as simple text in the MVC view?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have MVC website, and I would like to show some code snippets as text on my website. Something like this:

```
List<ImageInfoModel> imgList = new List<ImageInfoModel>();
string imgPath = @"~/Content/Images/ImageGallery/";
string tmbPath = @"~/Content/Images/ImageGallery/thumbnails/";

string imgFullPath = Server.MapPath(imgPath);
string tmbFullPath = Server.MapPath(tmbPath);
```

If I simply copy and paste this into my view with

code text

it messes things up because of @ symbol.

So my question is: How can I display C# code inside my view?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: check out `@Html.Raw` as a starting point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your View file, add a `@` wherever you start razor syntax. This will escape the Razor codes and treat it like a html code.

```
List<imageinfomodel> imgList = new List<imageinfomodel>
();
string imgPath = @@"~/Content/Images/ImageGallery/";
string tmbPath = @@"~/Content/Images/ImageGallery/thumbnails/";

string imgFullPath = Server.MapPath(imgPath);
string tmbFullPath = Server.MapPath(tmbPath);
```

Answer (score 0):

If its directly from a model why not try `@Html.Raw`<strike>or if its in the view you could prefix the statements with `@:`</strike>.

Comment: `@:` doesn't stop razor statement processing.  so `@:@model.prop is so cool` will still output the value of `model.prop`.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:
**Code behind**:

```
        string Sk = "List&lt;ImageInfoModel&gt; imgList = new List&lt;ImageInfoModel&gt;();<br/>";
        Sk += "string imgPath = @";
        Sk += "\"~/Content/Images/ImageGallery/\";<br/>";
        Sk += "string tmbPath = @";
        Sk += "\"~/Content/Images/ImageGallery/thumbnails/\";<br/>";
        Sk += "string imgFullPath = Server.MapPath(imgPath);<br/>string tmbFullPath = Server.MapPath(tmbPath);";
        ViewBag.Sk = Sk;
```

**View**:
@Html.Raw(ViewBag.Sk)